# getting error while adding dll reference in the c# .net windows application why?

Tags: c#, security, licensing

i have download the code from the codeProject web site but while runnig this i got the reference error of the dll in the reference folder. the dll file is located in my bin/debug/
folder. still it not found it. when i add this file from add reference tag i give the error 
that this is not valid com component.

please help in this

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

If the DLL is a COM library, you will need to [register it manually using regsvr32](https://web.archive.org/web/20090423050503/http://www.tech-faq.com:80/register-dll.shtml). Then you can access it by name from the COM tab of the Add Reference dialog (see below).

[image]
<sub>(source: [com.com](http://i.techrepublic.com.com/gallery/182704-467-375.jpg))</sub>

If, on the other hand the DLL is native code as Jon Skeet suggested, you will only be able to use it by p/invoking to call its interface directly - if this is the case, it is best to create a class that acts as a wrapper around the DLL - that puts a layer of indirection between your code and all the p/invoke stuff so your code isn't too tightly bound to the interface of the DLL.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you haven't said which project it is... but my *guess* is that you're trying to add a reference to a native code DLL, rather than either a COM library or a .NET class library.

If you provide more details, we're far more likely to be able to help you.

Comment: i am creating the project for generating the license key for my product and this code i have downloaded from codeProject. the dll they have provided is not working. reference are missing for that dll 
is there any solution for the same ?